# Counterexample to Cauchy product theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, cauchy-product

The Cauchy product theorem for infinite series of complex numbers states if $\sum  a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are two absolutely convergent series then the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$, where $c_n=\sum_{p+q=n} a_pb_q$ is also absolutely convergent and $\sum c_n=(\sum  a_n)(\sum b_n)$.

I was wondering if there is a counter example if we weaken the conditions, specifically:

Do there exist series $\sum  a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ which are both convergent but not both absolutely convergent, such that the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ converges, but $\sum c_n \neq(\sum  a_n)(\sum b_n)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a counterexample satisfying the property you seek cannot exist, which we can see by [Cesàro's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Ces%C3%A0ro's_theorem).

For a series $\sum d_n$, the Cesàro sum is the limit of the average of the partial sums:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^nd_i$$

If a sum is classically summable, then it is also Cesàro summable, and its Cesàro sum matches its classical sum.

Now Cesàro's theorem says that in general if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are conditionally convergent, then the Cauchy product will be Cesàro summable, and its Cesàro sum will be $(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n),$ even though it need not be classically convergent to $(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n).$

Hence what you are asking for cannot happen. For $c_n=\sum_{p+q=n} a_pb_q$, either $\sum c_n$ is not classically convergent, but it is Cesàro summable and its Cesàro sum is $(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n).$

Or else it *is* classically convergent, in which case it must still converge to its Cesàro sum $(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n).$